# How to prevent Visual Studio from targeting new class library projects to .NETStandard?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created a blank web project in Visual Studio 2017 using the .NET Framework 4.6.2. This project gets created correctly:

[image: correct project generation]

I go to the Solution Explorer, select the Solution and select the "Add Project" menu option:

[image: add new project]

I make sure that I select the ".NET Standard" option and add a new Class Library project to my solution:

[image: .NET library]

When I select the project and view its properties, the target framework is not the 4.6.2 I specified, it's .NET Standard 1.4:

[image: Bad framework target]

Why is Visual Studio assigning the wrong framework to new projects? Is there any way to prevent it from doing this? Are there any workarounds? Is there some way to convert an existing .NET core project into a .NET Framework project?

Comment: You have choosen ".net Standard" on the "Visual C#" list of supported templates, if you want to target .net classic choose "Windows Classic Desktop".

Comment: I think that's a workaround @Gusman - but it works. Any idea what .NET standard doesn't map to .NET framework? Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: No, it's not a workaround, that's how it works, if you choose ".net Standard" the projects will point to the .net Standard framework, if you choose "Windows Classic Desktop" it will point to the classic framework, like if you choose ".net Core" it will target .net Core framework.

Comment: I had no idea .NET Standard was a separate thing. I was under the assumption that core and framework were the only two options. The dropdown menu at the top that says .NET Framework with the version confuses the issue because I thought that menu dictated the version. Thanks for clearing that up @Gusman!

Comment: That's simply the new thing you need to learn, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff and next time you can pick up the right project type.

Comment: I think this must be one of the benefits to using .NET Core - you don't have to rely on arcane legacy knowledge of multiple indistinguishable products just to create a simple project! How is anyone new to .NET supposed to know which option to choose? "Standard" "Classic" and "Core" are practically synonyms, "Portable" won't work, and "Windows Classic Desktop" offers zero indication that's what I want! I'm trying to create a data layer class library for a Web API project, not a desktop app!